# C++ expression templates lifetime

Tags: c++

I was looking at the example of expression templates at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates. Then I tried to make a simple symbolic expression tree, i.e. to add constants and variables like a + b + 10. So I started with

```
#include <iostream>


template<typename E>
class Expression {
public:
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        return expression().print(os);
    }
    E const& expression() const { return static_cast<E const&>(*this); }
};

class Var : public Expression<Var> {
public:
    Var(const char name)
            : name_(name)
    {}

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        return os << name_;
    }
private:
    const char name_;
};

class Constant : public Expression<Constant> {
public:
    Constant(const double value)
            : value_(value)
    {}

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        return os << value_;
    }

private:
    const double value_;
};

template<typename E1, typename E2>
class ExpressionSum : public Expression<ExpressionSum<E1,E2>> {
    E1 const& u_;
    E2 const& v_;
public:
    ExpressionSum(E1 const& u, E2 const& v) : u_(u), v_(v)
    {
    }

    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        os << "(";
        u_.print(os);
        os << " + ";
        v_.print(os);
        os << ")";
        return os;
    }
};
template <typename E1, typename E2>
ExpressionSum<E1,E2> operator+(Expression<E1> const& u, Expression<E2> const& v) {
    return ExpressionSum<E1, E2>(u.expression(), v.expression());
}

int main() {
    Var a('a');
    Var b('b');
    Constant c(1.0);

    auto expr = a + b + c;
    expr.print(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;

    auto expr2 = expr + Constant{2.0};
    expr2.print(std::cout);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The expression `expr` is fine, but I cannot reuse `expr` to build another expression like `expr2` since the temporary `ExpressionSum` of `a+b` is already destroyed. Is there a way to store these temporaries in the expression?

Comment: I am not fully sure to understand your question, but I think to use combined expressions, you'll need to use them in a tree (AST).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing reference here:

```
template<typename E1, typename E2>
class ExpressionSum : public Expression<ExpressionSum<E1,E2>> {
    E1 const& u_; // <------| These are references
    E2 const& v_; // <------|
public:
    ExpressionSum(E1 const& u, E2 const& v) : u_(u), v_(v)
    { }

    // ...
};
```

These does not cause lifetime extension. The wikipedia article assume the expression template is never stored and only live in the same statement as the expression.

Store them as value:

```
template<typename E1, typename E2>
class ExpressionSum : public Expression<ExpressionSum<E1,E2>> {
    E1 u_; // <------| Fixed!
    E2 v_; // <------|
public:
    ExpressionSum(E1 const& u, E2 const& v) : u_(u), v_(v)
    { }

    // ...
};
```

You can also extend `std::tuple` to piggyback on it's EBO:

```
template<typename E1, typename E2>
class ExpressionSum : public Expression<ExpressionSum<E1,E2>>, private std::tuple<E1, E2> {
    auto u_() const -> E1 const& { return std::get<0>(*this); }
    auto v_() const -> E2 const& { return std::get<1>(*this); }
public:
    ExpressionSum(E1 const& u, E2 const& v) : std::tuple<E1, E2>(u, v)
    { }

    // ...
};
```

Comment: This will cause deep copies when the expressions are not mere constants anymore, right?

Comment: @shuhalo depends. Most of the time, expression template hardly contain anything. A reference is usually much more heavy than a reference to an object. So in a sense it's even faster to copy than to copy a pointer (passing by reference)

Answer (score 4):

### Avoid CRTP: Use Argument-Dependent Lookup to simplify the library

We want to keep things as simple as possible. The Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (and it's relatives) are powerful tools, but they increase compile-times and are cumbersome when you want to expand what you're doing.

By taking advantage of [argument dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), we can implement operator overloading *without having a base class*. This greatly simplifies the design of the library. I'll explain more about this in the examples given below

#### Avoid lifetime issues: store subexpressions by value unless explicitly using `std::ref`

We want to keep this library simple. An expression is either a constant, a unary operation and an input, or a binary operation and an input. There aren't any class invariants - the inputs can take on any value, and the operation itself is stored based on it's type, so it can only have 1 value.

This means that we can represent expressions as **aggregate types**, making them trivially constructible, trivially copyable, trivially destructible, and reducing both compiletimes and the size of the resulting binary.

```
namespace expr // We need to put them in a namespace so we can use ADL
{
    template<class Value>
    class Constant
    {
       public:
        Value value;
    };

    template<class Op, class Input>
    class UnaryOp
    {
       public:
        Op op;
        Input input; 
    };
    template<class Op, class Left, class Right>
    class BinaryOp
    {
       public:
        Op op;
        Left lhs;
        Right rhs; 
    };
}
```

#### Simplify operator overloads: use namespace scoping

If we write the operator overloads in a namespace, **they'll only be considered when working with types from that namespace**. This means we can avoid having a base class, and we can use unconstrained templates.

```
namespace expr 
{
    template<class A>
    auto operator-(A const& a)
    {
        return UnaryOp<Negate, A>{{}, a}; 
    }
    template<class A, class B>
    auto operator+(A const& a, B const& b) 
    {
        return BinaryOp<Plus, A, B>{{}, a, b}; 
    }
    template<class A, class B>
    auto operator-(A const& a, B const& b) 
    {
        return BinaryOp<Minus, A, B>{{}, a, b}; 
    }
    template<class A, class B>
    auto operator*(A const& a, B const& b) {
        return BinaryOp<Times, A, B>{{}, a, b}; 
    }
}
```

#### Simplify evaluation: Operation types know how to evaluate their inputs

This is pretty simple to achieve - basically, any operation is a functor type that knows how to evaluate the inputs. In C++20, this can be achieved with lambdas, but for our purposes we'll just overload the `operator()`.

```
namespace expr {
    class Negate {
        template<class A>
        constexpr auto operator()(A&& a) const 
            noexcept(noexcept(-a))
            -> decltype(-a)
        {
            return -a; 
        }
    };
    class Plus {
    public:
        template<class A, class B>
        constexpr auto operator()(A&& a, B&& b) const
            noexcept(noexcept(a + b))
            -> decltype(a + b) 
        {
            return a + b; 
        }
    };
    class Minus {
    public:
        template<class A, class B>
        constexpr auto operator()(A&& a, B&& b) const
            noexcept(noexcept(a - b))
            -> decltype(a - b) 
        {
            return a - b; 
        }
    };
    class Times {
    public:
        template<class A, class B>
        constexpr auto operator()(A&& a, B&& b) const
            noexcept(noexcept(a * b))
            -> decltype(a * b) 
        {
            return a * b; 
        }
    };
}
```

#### Take advantage of pattern-matching with namespace-scope `evaluate`

Rather than having it as a member function, we can take advantage of pattern matching and recursion when writing an `evaluate` function at namespace scope.

```
namespace expr
{
    // This one is applied to things that aren't constants or expressions
    template<class Thing>
    auto evaluate(Thing const& t) -> Thing const& {
        return t; 
    }
    template<class Value>
    auto evaluate(Constant<Value> const& value) {
        return evaluate(value.value);
    }
    template<class Op, class Input>
    auto evaluate(UnaryOp<Op, Input> const& expr) {
        return expr.op(evaluate(expr.value)); 
    }
    template<class Op, class LHS, class RHS>
    auto evaluate(BinaryOp<Op, LHS, RHS> const& expr) {
        return expr.op(evaluate(expr.lhs), evaluate(expr.rhs)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `auto` with expression templates. If the smart people behind the `Eigen` library [can't make it work](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicPitfalls.html), you don't really have a chance either.

I mean, you can copy just about every value involved but that's generally the thing you want to avoid with expression templates.